# Looking through different combinations through matrix using just visited int variable?

Tags: java

I am looking at this topcoder problem here:

http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemDetail&rd=4725&pm=2288

Under the java section there is this code :

```
public class KiloManX {
    boolean ddd = false;

    int[] s2ia(String s) {
        int[] r = new int[s.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            r[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0' ;
        }
        return r;
    }

    public int leastShots(String[] damageChart, int[] bossHealth) {
        int i, j, k;
        int n = damageChart.length;
        int[][] dc = new int[n][];
        int[] cost = new int[1 << n];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dc[i] = s2ia(damageChart[i]) ;
        }
        for (i = 1; i < 1 << n; i++) {
            cost[i] = 65536 * 30000;

            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int pre = i - (1 << j);
                if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0) {
                    cost[i] = Math.min(cost[i], cost[pre] + bossHealth[j]) ;

                    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                        if ((i & (1 << k)) != 0 && k != j && dc[k][j] > 0) {
                            cost[i] = Math.min(cost[i],
                                cost[pre] + (bossHealth[j] + dc[k][j] - 1) / dc[k][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return cost[(1 << n) - 1] ;
    }

    static void pp(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what he is been done. So what I understand is :

1. `i` - keeps track of the visited nodes somehow(this is the most baffling part of the code)
2. `j` - is the monster we want to defeat
3. `k` - is the previous monster's weapon we are using to defeat j
4. `dc` is the input array of string into a matrix
5. `cost`, keep cost at each step, some sort of dynamic programming? I don't understand how `cost[1 << n]` can give the result?

What I understand is they are going through all the possible sets / combinations. What I am baffled by (even after executing and starring at this for more than a week) is:

6. how do they keep track of all the combinations?
7. I understand `pre` - is the cost of the previous monster defeated (*i.e.* how much cost we incurred there), but I don't understand how you get it from just `(i - 1 << j)`.

I have executed the program(debugger), stared at it for more than a week, and tried to decode it, but I am baffled by the bit-manipulation part of the code. Can someone please shed light on this?

Comment: One way to understand code is by running it with a debugger. Step through one line at a time and watch the values of all of the variables. The debugger is often used to find bugs, but it is also useful for learning how working code does what it does.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice as I wrote above I did just that, I still don't understandwhich is why I am asking here :)

Comment: Note that `1 << n` is equivalent to `Math.pow(2, n) -1`.

Comment: It also appears that the author is using Dynamic Programming. If you are unfamiliar with this technique, you should definitely learn about it. Many TC problems can be solved with it.

Comment: No, @Code-Apprentice, `1 << n` is (roughly) equivalent to `Math.pow(2, n)`.  (No -1).  "Roughly" because the data types differ.

Comment: oh...it pads 0s, not 1s...my bad.

Comment: @JohnBollinger By "roughly" I assume you are alluding to the difference in efficiency of the calculation? Or are you referring to the potential of a negative result? Or both?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, the data types differ.  Additionally, the result of `Math.pow()` may be off from the exact result by one ulp in either direction; if it happens to be one ulp low then truncating the result to an integer yields a result that might surprise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `cost`, keep cost at each step, some sort of dynamic programming?

They are partial costs, yes, but characterizing them as *per-step* costs misses the most important significance of the indices into this array.  More below.

> I don't understand how `cost[1 << n]` can give the result?

That doesn't give any result by itself, of course.  It just declares an array with 2<sup>n</sup> elements.

> how do they keep track of all the combinations?

See below.  This is closely related to why the `cost` array is declared the size it is.

> I understand `pre` - is the cost of the previous monster defeated (i.e. how much cost we incurred there), but I don't understand how you get it from just `(i - 1 << j)`.

Surely `pre` is not itself a cost.  It is, however, used conditionally as an *index* into the `cost` array.  Now consider the condition:

```
                if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0) {
```

The expression `i & (1 << j)` tests whether bit `j` of the value of `i` is set.  When it is, `i - (1 << j)` (*i.e.* `pre`) evaluates to the the result of turning off bit `j` of the value of `i`.  That should clue you in that the indices of `cost` are bit masks.  The size of that array (`1 << n`) is another clue: it is the number of distinct `n`-bit bitmasks.

The trick here is a relatively common one, and a good one to know.  Suppose you have a set of N objects, and you want somehow to represent all of its subsets (== all the distinct combinations of its elements).  Each subset is characterized by whether each of the N objects is an element or not.  You can represent that as N numbers, each either 0 or 1 -- *i.e.* N bits.  Now suppose you string those bits together into N-bit numbers.  Every integer from 0 (inclusive) to 2<sup>N</sup> (exclusive) has a distinct pattern of its least-significant N bits, so each corresponds to different subset.

The code presented uses exactly this sort of correspondence to encode the different subsets of the set of bosses as different indices into the `cost` array -- which answers your other question of how it keeps track of combinations.  Given one such index `i` that represents a subset containing boss `j`, the index `i - (1 << j)` represents the set obtained from it by removing boss `j`.

Roughly speaking, then, the program proceeds by optimizing the cost of each non-empty subset by checking all the ways to form it from a subset with one element fewer.  `(1 << n) - 1` is the index corresponding to the whole set, so at the end, that element of `cost` contains the overall optimized value.

Comment: Thats was exactly where I was stuck! I know that this is some sort of subset technique, but I dint know that i - (1<<j) was the subset minus the current boss. Thank you!